# Bare Metal Arm (AM1808) - Read from Kick Registers

Tags: c, embedded, arm, bare-metal, arm9

I am trying to do some pin multiplexing on my bare metal AM1808, but I can't seem to write the kick register? Or, more specifically, I seem to be unable to read back the values I tried to write.

Here is my code:

```
#define SYSCFG_BASE ((void*volatile)0x01C14000)
#define SYSCFG_KICK0R (*((unsigned int*volatile)(SYSCFG_BASE + 0x38)))
#define SYSCFG_KICK1R (*((unsigned int*volatile)(SYSCFG_BASE + 0x3C)))

#define KICK0_UNLOCK  0x83E70B13
#define KICK1_UNLOCK  0x95A4F10
#define KICK0_LOCK    0x0
#define KICK1_LOCK    0x0

static void
gpio_init (int diode)
{
  int status = 0;
  asm volatile (
    "mrs %[ps],cpsr" : [ps]"=&r"(status)
  );
  printf("mode:  0x%x\n", status & 0x1F);

  printf("kick0: 0x%x", SYSCFG_KICK0R);
  SYSCFG_KICK0R = KICK0_UNLOCK;
  printf("   ->  0x%x\n", SYSCFG_KICK0R);

  printf("kick1: 0x%x", SYSCFG_KICK1R);
  SYSCFG_KICK1R = KICK1_UNLOCK;
  printf("   ->  0x%x\n", SYSCFG_KICK1R);

  /* pinmux stuff */

  SYSCFG_KICK0R = KICK0_LOCK;
  SYSCFG_KICK1R = KICK1_LOCK;
}
```

which outputs:

```
mode:  0x13
kick0: 0x0   ->  0x0
kick1: 0x0   ->  0x0
```

Am I generally not able to read the kick registers although I am in supervisor mode? If so, how can I test if I unlocked the syscfg correctly?

**UPDATE**:
As it turns out, the problem I was having was not related to the pin multiplexing, or the kick registers, but instead I had an error in the top level logic that used the correctly multiplexed GPIO pins. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The AM1808 TechRef says this in 10.2.2 Kicker Mecahanism Protection: "The Kick registers are disabled in silicon revision 2 and later. The SYSCFG registers are always unlocked and writes to the Kick registers have no functional effect"  Maybe you have a rev 2 device?

Comment: @MichaelBurr the REVID register of syscfg contains `0x4E840102` But I could not find anything in the manual if this references revision 2?

Comment: I have a AM335x manual at hand and for that KICK registers are write only. Please check if your manual states something similar.

Comment: @auselen thanks. my manual states that for the AM1808 the kick registers are both read and writable though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the datasheet,  your value for `KICK1` should be `0x95A4F1E0`, your code has `0x95A4F10` which doesn't match. It's visually quite clear in your code that the second value is shorter than the first, which is a warning signal.

It also says, as pointed out in a comment, that Rev 2 of the hardware no longer has the kick registers so check that, too.

Also, make sure calling `printf()` in that sequence of scary poking is safe.

Comment: Thanks, The Kick1 Constant had a typo, which I fixed. Unfortunately, I still read 0 from the kick register. I wrote the printf in question myself, what should I look for in terms of safety?